# Como inserir e reexibir uma lista de itens no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

O código abaixo permite a inserção de ***n*** itens no array `$scope.items[]`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.user = {};
        $scope.produtoTrib = {};
 $scope.items = [];
 var sum = 1;
 
 $scope.addItem = function (user){
   $scope.items.push({
    nome: user.nome,
    email: user.email,
    soma: sum++
   });
    user.nome = '';
    user.email = ''; 
 };
      
     
    $scope.addAtributos = function (produto){
        $scope.produtoTrib = produto;
 };
      
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">

<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>Nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome">
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
    
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.telefone">
    <input type="text" hidden name="email" ng-model="user.cpf">
    
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
</form>
<br />

<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
ID: {{item.soma}}<br />
Nome: {{item.nome}}<br />
E-mail: {{item.email}}<br /><br />
<!-- {{item.telefone}} - {{item.cpf}} -->
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="addAtributos(item)">Atributos</button>
<hr />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Atributos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Telefone: </label><input type="text" name="telefone" ng-model="produtoTrib.telefone">
        <label>CPF: </label><input type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="produtoTrib.cpf">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Atualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Supondo que o sistema trabalhe com autenticação de usuário:

→ Como armazenar os ***n*** itens inseridos por um usuário ***x***?

→ Como *reexibir* a estrutura acima, contendo todos os itens inseridos pelo usuário ***x***?

Comment: Você terá de fazer duas requisições ajax. Uma quando da load(retornando os registros) no controlador e outra quando adiciona o item(dando insert no banco). Dá uma lida sobre Ajax...

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche poderia me explicar melhor por chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52952/room-for-luccasrodrigo-and-rodrigo-sartori-jarouche

Comment: @luccasrodrigo sua pergunta está meio confusa. Se o seu sistema trabalhar com autenticação do usuário o servidor só irá retornar as opções referentes a esse usuário logado. Não vejo sentido em tratar isso no cliente, mesmo porque as operações no cliente não são seguras

Comment: Olá @Sorack, não desejo tratar isso no "cliente". A questão é que um determinado usuário pode inserir vários itens, que serão cadastrados no banco de dados, e estes só deverão ser exibidos para o usuário que os inseriu.

Comment: Então isso deve ser tratado no servidor. Só que vc não forneceu nenhuma informação sobre servidor e banco de dados

Comment: @Sorack, mas é exatamente isso que preciso. O que e como devo fazer pra inserir esses dados e retorná-los reexibindo uma lista destes...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, itensService) {
    $rootScope.userLogado = {id: 666, nome: 'Malandro'}; //Se tivesse autenticação, teria guardado os dados do usuário em algum lugar
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.produtoTrib = {};
    $scope.items = [];
    var sum = 1;
    $scope.loadItems = function() {
        itensService.getItemsByidUsuario($rootScope.userLogado.id).then(function(obj) {
            $scope.items = obj.data;
        })
    }
    $scope.addItem = function(user) {
        $scope.items.push({
            idUserLogado: $rootScope.userLogado.id, // identifica o malandro que esta logado na hora do cadastro.
            nome: user.nome,
            email: user.email,
            soma: sum++
        });
        user.nome = '';
        user.email = '';
    };


    $scope.addAtributos = function(produto) {
        $scope.produtoTrib = produto;
    };

});

app.service("itemsService", function($http) {
    this.getItemsByidUsuario = function(idUserLogado) {
        //SELECT * FROM items WHERE idUserLogado = {{idUserLogado}}
        return $http.get("api/getItemsByidUsuario/" + idUserLogado);
    }
});
```

```html
...
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador" ng-init="loadItems();">
...
```

Comment: Olá @ThiagoRobert, mas como faço pra inserir a lista de itens no BD via MySQL e reexibir a mesma estrutura a partir de uma consulta?